# I'm getting doctors links by submitting the post requests using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

try:

    for count in range(123401,123405):
        ctl00_RightContetHolder_TextBox1 = count

        r = requests.post('http://karnatakamedicalcouncil.com/RenewalReport.aspx',
                                  data={'ctl00_RightContetHolder_TextBox1': count, 'Search': "submit"})

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

        for i in soup.find('table', {'class': 'mGrid'}):
            for links in i.find('a',class_='Viewdetails'):
                print links

except:
    pass
```

I am trying to get each of the links in the mGrid tables, but haven't been able to retrieve them with beautiful soup. I don't understand why the anchor tags are not being found, or if they are being found why they are not being printed. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It missing required data `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION`, to get it you need create `GET` request and extract hidden input value with that ID then you can create `POST` or search request with that data.

```
url = 'http://karnatakamedicalcouncil.com/RenewalReport.aspx'

html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

VIEWSTATE = soup.find(id='__VIEWSTATE')['value']
EVENTVALIDATION = soup.find(id='__EVENTVALIDATION')['value']

for count in range(123401,123405):
    data = {
            '__VIEWSTATE' : VIEWSTATE,
            '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED' : '',
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' : EVENTVALIDATION,
            'ctl00$RightContetHolder$TextBox1': count,
            'ctl00$RightContetHolder$hdnSearch': "Search",
          }

    r = requests.post(url, data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    for links in soup.findAll('a', class_='Viewdetails'):
        print links['href']
```

Comment: welcome, if it solved please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: can u plz tell me, how this program works, honestly i didnt get how it is done.

Comment: and how this came  "ctl00$RightContetHolder$hdnSearch': "Search" as it is below the search box element

Comment: and how this came  "ctl00$RightContetHolder$hdnSearch': "Search" as it is below the search box element

Comment: it is because the elements are wrapped in the `<form>`